# UPDSRVPGM and CRTSRVPGM difference in ile concept

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Can someone explain the conceptual difference between UPDSRVPGM and CRTSRVPGM in the ile concepts. I mean to say why can't we always use CRTSRVPGM, why is there a need or advantage to use UPDSRVPGM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use CRTSRVPGM...In fact I recommend doing so as some of the meta data in the *SRVPGM object is not updated when UPDSRVPGM is used.

The only real advantage to UPSRVPGM is when your *SRVPGM consists of multiple modules and your change management process has one or more of the following issues:

- doesn't keep the *MODULE objects around.
- you can't trust the *MODULE objects it finds.
- doesn't support automated rebuilds of the other *MODULE objects

In those case if you have a *SRVPGM made up of 5 modules, and you need to make a change to a single procedure in one of the modules.  You can make the change, then use CRTxxxMOD and UPDSRVPGM to update that single module inside the existing service program.

Comment: The other use for UPDSRVPGM is when you have circular references in your service programs. You can create the service programs with the option to ignore unresolved references, then after all service programs are created, you can use UPDSRVPGM to resolve any remaining unresolved references.